# Using pandas.io.json.json_normalize() with empty list attributes

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm using `pandas.io.json.json_normalize()` to convert some json into a dataframe, which is then pushed to an SQLite database via `df.to_sql()`.

However, I'm getting `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.` when progressing with this, I think due to one of my json fields being an empty array.

I understand I can pass additional path arguments to `json_normalize` to have it pull out array values and augment the rows with the parent data:

`json_normalize(json_data, 'field_name_of_empty_array_value')`

However I can't use this for this instance, as the array is empty and so it returns no values.

Is there a way to set the empty list value to `None`, or to serialize the empty list via the `json_serialize` function? Or do I need to do this on the returned `dataFrame`?

The reason I want to understand whether this is possible is to limit the complexity when dealing with more difficult `json` which may have empty array values nested deep within its structure.

I've search for this specific question but can't seem to find an example dealing with this specific case, and not sure the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) covers it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this isn't possible. So instead, I'm using `json_normalize` on the full `json` object, then splitting as required using `DataFrame` operations, before converting back to `json` via `df.to_json`, and using `json_normalize` with different arguments - specifically, the `record_path` argument to create records based on the array entries as required.