# from pandas.io.json import json_normalize with empty list

Tags: json, pandas

I'm using pandas.io.json.json_normalize() to convert a json object into a dataframe(flatten data). The json has a one nested key with empty items. I need this item to return Null or an empty string when I run normalize.  Such as:

```
    `df_normalize = json_normalize(python_json_nested_data, ['items'],meta=['key', 'state','date'],
                          record_prefix='category.', errors='raise')`
```

`python_json_nested_data = [{"key":"KEY-1","state":"MA", "items":["orange", "meat", "bread"], "date":"Y16"},
            {"key":"KEY-2","state":"MA", "items":["apple", "bread"], "date":"Y15"},
            {"key":"KEY-3","state":"TX", "items":["bread"], "date":"Y16"},
            {"key":"KEY-4","state":"TN", "items":["apple", "bread"], "date":"Y16"},
            {"key":"KEY-5","state":"TN", "items":["apple", "orange"], "date":"Y15"},
            {"key":"KEY-6","state":"TN", "items": [], "date":"Y14"}]`

What am I missing? I've followed links from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023807/using-pandas-io-json-json-normalize-with-empty-list-attributes) and understood that it was a bug that was fixed in a prior pandas version. I'm using 0.25?

I would like results to include row 10:

`+----+--------------+-------+---------+--------+
|    | category.0   | key   | state   | date   |
|----+--------------+-------+---------+--------|
|  0 | orange       | KEY-1 | MA      | Y16    |
|  1 | meat         | KEY-1 | MA      | Y16    |
|  2 | bread        | KEY-1 | MA      | Y16    |
|  3 | apple        | KEY-2 | MA      | Y15    |
|  4 | bread        | KEY-2 | MA      | Y15    |
|  5 | bread        | KEY-3 | TX      | Y16    |
|  6 | apple        | KEY-4 | TN      | Y16    |
|  7 | bread        | KEY-4 | TN      | Y16    |
|  8 | apple        | KEY-5 | TN      | Y15    |
|  9 | orange       | KEY-5 | TN      | Y15    |
+----+--------------+-------+---------+--------+
+10  + nan          + KEY-6 + TX      + Y14    +`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(python_json_nested_data)
df = df.explode('items').reset_index(drop=['index'])
print(df)

      key state   items date
0   KEY-1    MA  orange  Y16
1   KEY-1    MA    meat  Y16
2   KEY-1    MA   bread  Y16
3   KEY-2    MA   apple  Y15
4   KEY-2    MA   bread  Y15
5   KEY-3    TX   bread  Y16
6   KEY-4    TN   apple  Y16
7   KEY-4    TN   bread  Y16
8   KEY-5    TN   apple  Y15
9   KEY-5    TN  orange  Y15
10  KEY-6    TN     NaN  Y14
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me only catch is I need to use from pandas.io.json import json_normalize.
I get an AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize' only importing pandas.